# Creating polygon from two not connected linestrings using shapely

Tags: shapely, linestring, polygon-creation

I'd like to know if there is a way to create a polygon in shapely from two not connected linestrings. I've been struggling with this question from some hours now and I can't find a way to deal with it.

[image: Figure]

For example, I'd like to have the polygon with those linestrings as its exterior coords.

```py
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

p1 = Polygon([1.32, 7.66], [1.4, 5.56], [2.98, 4.5], [5.86, 4], [12.16, 4.88])
p2 = Polygon([1.62, 0], [2, 1], [3.16, 1.68], [5, 2], [8.44, 2.14], [9.92, 0.58], [12, 0], [13.62, 0.8])
```

Comment: By definition, a polygon is composed of the vertices which describe a closed ring. Your vertices are not closed rings. They are therefore not polygons. There are other requirements besides *closed* (not crossing, not touching other parts,...) but you need to work on that first.

Answer (score 7):

You can get the lines' coordinates and use them to make a polygon. But it depends. In many cases, you will probably have invalid polygon.

- Let's make two lines using the coordinates in your question:

  ```
  from shapely.geometry import Polygon, LineString
  l1 = LineString([[1.32, 7.66], [1.4, 5.56], [2.98, 4.5], [5.86, 4], [12.16, 4.88]])
  l2 = LineString([[1.62, 0], [2, 1], [3.16, 1.68], [5, 2], [8.44, 2.14], [9.92, 0.58], [12, 0], [13.62, 0.8]])

  p = Polygon([*list(l1.coords), *list(l2.coords)])
  ```

  [image]

  As you see, there are many self-intersecting edges. So the result is an invalid polygon.
- Let's reverse the `l2`'s coordinates:

  ```
  p = Polygon([*list(l1.coords), *list(l2.coords)[::-1]])
  ```

  [image]

  Again, self-intersecting edges.
- Let's change `l2`'s location. (added 10 to y-coordinate):

  ```
  l2 = LineString([[1.62, 10], [2, 11], [3.16, 11.68], [5, 12], [8.44, 12.14], [9.92, 10.58], [12, 10], [13.62, 10.8]])
  p = Polygon([*list(l1.coords), *list(l2.coords)])
  ```

  [image]
- Let's reverse the `l2`'s coordinates:

  ```
  p = Polygon([*list(l1.coords), *list(l2.coords)[::-1]])
  ```

  [image]

  Now, this is a **valid** polygon.

Briefly, you cannot be sure if the result polygon will be valid. It depends.

Comment: Oh nice, thank you for your answer !! To manage the situation, I've made a list comprehensive loop with all the combinations of coordinates using `itertools.product()` and I'm only keeping the valid ones with `shapely.obj.is_valid`.